# How to build javadoc from sources within a .jar file?

Tags: jar, documentation, javadoc

I have to build Javadoc from *myCode.jar* that contains both sources and class files.
Can I do it without extracting the jar?

According to http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/javadoc.html#classpath I should be able to do so this way: `C:\>javadoc -d docs -classpath myCode.jar net\kem\jmx\CacheManagerMBean.java`
However, I get the following error:

```
javadoc: error - File not found: "net\kem\jmx\CacheManagerMBean.java"
[search path for source files: [myCode.jar]]
[search path for class files: [C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.5.0_17\jre\lib\rt.jar, C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.5.0_17\jre\lib\jsse.jar,
 C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.5.0_17\jre\lib\jce.jar, C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.5.0_17\jre\lib\charsets.jar, C:\Program Files\Java\jd
k1.5.0_17\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar, C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.5.0_17\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar, C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.5.0_17\jre
\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar, C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.5.0_17\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar, C:\Projects\RenderClusterController\WebCo
ntent\WEB-INF\lib\makoRenderJMX.jar]]
[done in 360 ms]
1 error
```

It seems, javadoc cannot find the source files within the jar. I'm confident that the sources are there.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Double Check that the jar actually contains the source files(open it as a zip file) 
You might also want to try adjusting the net\kem... to dots instead of \ or removing it altogether

Answer (score 3):

Some first tests indicate it does not work (at least on OpenJDK 1.6.0_20, which I have here).

So, I looked into the source (browsable in a [mercurial web-interface](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk6/jdk6/langtools/file/eafc26d73d9d/src/share/classes/com/sun/tools/javadoc/)). Javadoc (in the version there, which may differ from the one I have here) uses quite some bits of Javac in its for the operation, and it looks like both are using the `javax.tools.JavaFileManager` interface to implement access to their source files, specifically in the subinterface `StandardJavaFileManager`.

[This interface](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?javax/tools/StandardJavaFileManager.html) claims to be able to access zip file entries:

> This file manager creates file objects representing regular files, zip file entries, or entries in similar file system based containers.

But here how it is used (in [`JavaDocTool.getRootDocImpl()`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk6/jdk6/langtools/file/eafc26d73d9d/src/share/classes/com/sun/tools/javadoc/JavadocTool.java)):

```
  148                 String name = it.head;
  149                 if (!docClasses && name.endsWith(".java") && new File(name).exists()) {
  150                     JavaFileObject fo = fm.getJavaFileObjects(name).iterator().next();
  151                     docenv.notice("main.Loading_source_file", name);
  152                     JCCompilationUnit tree = parse(fo);
  153                     classTrees.append(tree);
  154                 } else if (isValidPackageName(name)) {
  155                     names = names.append(name);
  156                 } else if (name.endsWith(".java")) {
  157                     docenv.error(null, "main.file_not_found", name);
  158                 } else {
  159                     docenv.error(null, "main.illegal_package_name", name);
  160                 }
```

The first case would apply in your call with a `.java` file - but since it does not exist as a file in the file system (`new File(name).exists()` returns false), this does not help, and you get instead the third case with a "file not found" error.

It looks like it could work when replacing this condition with a more suitable one (like `!fm.getJavaFileObjects(name).isEmpty()` - provided the context is initialized with a JavaFileManager which in fact looks in jar/zip files, which I did not check now.

So, you'll have either to unpack your source jar, or patch your javac implementation (preferably contributing this to the main javac source).