# Generating JavaDoc from String/Stream etc

Tags: javadoc

Is it possible to generate JavaDoc not from a .java file on disk but from a `String` or `InputStream` that contains Java source?

As I can see, `com.sun.tools.javadoc.Main.execute(...)` deals with disk files only. Is there another option rather than "hacking" `rt.jar`?

Answer (score 0):

I think it could work similarily to your [other javadoc question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2355344/how-to-build-javadoc-from-sources-within-a-jar-file). You would use `JavaDocTool` instead of `Main`, and give a Context object with a suitable StandardJavaFileManager implementation based on your in-memory source code.

If this question is still interesting someone, I could explore a bit more.